# How can I use powershell to get a list of service accounts with interactive logon privileges?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, service-accounts

By interactive logon, I mean logon types 2, 10, or 11.

I would like to write a PowerShell script that can give me a list of service accounts where interactive logon privileges are enabled.

I have tried two approaches.

I have tried to obtain the list of service accounts as follows:

```
Get-ADServiceAccount -Right -seInteractiveLogonRight
```

I’ve also tried to apply a filter on the user population:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {name like ‘svc*’} | 
Where-Object LogonType -eq 'Interactive'
```

Neither approach seems to work. With the first, I get a syntax error saying -Right does not exist as a valid parameter, and with the second I don’t get a response (just times out).

Help/pointers appreciated. Am quite new to Powershell so apologies if I’m missing anything fundamental.

Comment: As for this.. `Am quite new to Powershell`, that is all well and good, as we've all been there at one point or the other. Yet, this means you should really spend the time getting up to speed before you could potentially destroy your host or your enterprise environment as well as cause yourself undue stress, frustrations, errors, bad habits, et all. Never ever run code you do not understand, no matter where it comes from. Always test in a lab first. Always use `-WhatIf` and/or `-Confirm` to validate what you are doing before actual executions. Don't make up stuff, look it up first, before use.

Comment: Also, based on your post, spend the time learning about ADDS and AD objects, GPO. LPO etc. Youtube is your friend. search it for 'Beginning PowerShell` or intermediate, advanced, etc. Also, review the Windows ADAC and PowerShell History Viewer for writing PowerShell code. Lastly, validate your code using PSSCriptAnalyzer, Trace-Command, and ensure you have error handling and logging in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for this...

```
Get-ADServiceAccount -Right
```

... there is no such parameter for that cmdlet. Always, always check the help file what is and is not possible for a cmdlet, function, module, et al.

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Get-ADServiceAccount).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-ADServiceAccount).Parameters.Keys
# Results
<#
Verbose
Debug
ErrorAction
WarningAction
InformationAction
ErrorVariable
WarningVariable
InformationVariable
OutVariable
OutBuffer
PipelineVariable
AuthType
Credential
Filter
Identity
LDAPFilter
Partition
Properties
ResultPageSize
ResultSetSize
SearchBase
SearchScope
Server
#>
Get-help -Name Get-ADServiceAccount -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-ADServiceAccount -Full
Get-help -Name Get-ADServiceAccount -Online

# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Get-ADUser).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-ADUser).Parameters.Keys
# Results
<#
Verbose
Debug
ErrorAction
WarningAction
InformationAction
ErrorVariable
WarningVariable
InformationVariable
OutVariable
OutBuffer
PipelineVariable
AuthType
Credential
Filter
Identity
LDAPFilter
Partition
Properties
ResultPageSize
ResultSetSize
SearchBase
SearchScope
Server
#>
Get-help -Name  Get-ADUser -Examples
Get-help -Name  Get-ADUser -Full
Get-help -Name  Get-ADUser -Online
```

Logon Type is on the service object on the host, not a property via an AD user/computer object.

```
# Get all services
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $env:ComputerName | 
Select-Object -Property DisplayName, StartName, State  

# Filter for type
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $env:ComputerName | 
Where-Object { $PSItem.StartName -match 'LocalSystem' } | 
Select-Object -Property DisplayName, StartName, State
```

Rights are set in Policies (GPO or LPO) for a user/service account.

```
[xml]$report = Get-GPOReport -Name "Default Domain Policy" -ReportType XML
```

You can filter that report for specific information. Also, You can use the `secedit.exe` tool to get them.

> secedit commands
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/secedit

***This can give a rights report, but you will need to translate the SIDs to see the name in plain English.***

See this sample:

> https://www.powershellbros.com/get-user-rights-assignment-security-policy-settings

Though the tool has long since been depreciated, you can still use the `ntrights.exe` tool to get that information. The `ntights.exe` tool is in the Windows Resource Kit. That is if you have the old MSDN, TechNet media to get it, or know someone who does. If not you have to do stuff like this.

```
Find-Module -Name '*rights*'
# Results
<#
Version Name                  Repository Description                                                                                                                
------- ----                  ---------- -----------                                                                                                                
1.0.2   cUserRightsAssignment PSGallery  The cUserRightsAssignment module contains the cUserRight DSC resource that provides a mechanism to manage user rights:     
                                         logon rights and privileges. 
#>
```

Or download and use this tool...

```
https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=userrights
```

> The UserRights PowerShell module covers the following use cases:

- Get a list of users assigned a specific user right
- Get a list of user rights assigned to a specific user
- Get a list of all user rights with accounts
- Grant a user a or group a user right
- Revoke a user a or group a user right

... note: it is a legacy tool also.

Comment: Thanks very much. Appreciate your feedback as well. I did infact have a browse on YouTube and on the WWW but couldn’t find anything that I could use. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. Yea, when you end up searching for stuff, as a rule, you really need t get creative with those search strings. You'll often never find what you are after in a simple search or all you'd want. So, break the string into pieces, to get even partial results, and/or use absolute strings, partial strings, concatenated strings, etc.  [A good book on such topics is this one](https://www.amazon.com/Google-Hacking-Penetration-Testers-Johnny/dp/0128029641). It's not about PowerShell, but all about discovering stuff, but can be used in almost any search scenarios, despite the title.